# Strip HTML-like characters (not markup)  from XML with XSLT?

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to strip all HTML from XML with XSLT,
like PHP `strip_tags()` ?

I want to keep the text, but remove all formatting, etc.
This will be taking place before truncating.

```
   Hey Kurt, &lt;br&gt; I'd like to suggest that we start inventorying a system feature list at a &lt;br&gt; high-level. From there, we would define the requirements of the features. &lt;br&gt; Next, design to the requirements, develop, test, deploy..wash, rinse, and &lt;br&gt; repeat.. &lt;br&gt; I.E. &lt;br&gt; Event Calendar &lt;br&gt; - Requirement No. 1 &lt;br&gt; - Requirement No. 2
```

Comment: You want to remove it from the XSLT or from the XML?

Comment: Is the HTML escaped within the XML with &lt; and &gt; or does it contain < and > signs? Can we get a example of the XML?

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck, There is no strong reason why the text replacement you need should be done with XSLT (although something like this could be attempted). This is not HTML -- there is no HTML markup -- just *escaped* characters. If this was *unescaped*, real XHTML markup, then the solution in XSLT is both powerful and trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution on various places in the internet using Google:

Some examples of my research:
[here](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/05/17/stripping-html-tags-when-using-xslt.aspx), [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2008/08/30/strip-out-html-tags-to-display-plain-text-in-xslt.aspx), [here](http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.com/2011/06/removing-html-tags-using-xslt.html)

```xml
<!-- Calling the template that removes tag -->
<xsl:call-template name="remove-html">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="{HtmlBody}"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<!-- This will remove the tag -->
<xsl:template name="remove-html">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="remove-html">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```