# C# Strip HTML Markup in XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, strip-tags, xmltextreader

i really hope someone can help me with this issue. The solution should be on C#.

I have a xml file with the size of 36 MB and with 900k lines. On some nodes it has a lot of html markup and some invalid markup like

```
<Obs><p>
<jantes -="" .="" 22.000="" apenas="" exclusive="" kms.="" leve="" liga="" o=""> </jantes></p>
```

I've tried different ways to clean this file but only one way is able to perform the task, however, as this is being executed on a web application it's blocking the application and taking around 6 minutes to finish the task and consuming around 450MB in memory.

As this file is an invalid xml i cannot use XmlTextReader.
Using XLST, based on [Strip HTML-like characters (not markup)  from XML with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043103/strip-html-like-characters-not-markup-from-xml-with-xslt) ,strangely i'm also with problems with HTML Entities.

The process that worked (with some tweaks) is the following on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19652/HTML-Tag-Stripper

Thanks

**Edit:**

Following Kevin's suggestions. I'm trying to build a solution using HTML Agility Pack.
At least to do some benchmarks. 
I'm stuck however. Imagine the following xml node:

```
<Obs><p> I WANT THIS TEXT<jantes -="" .="" 22.000="" apenas="" exclusive="" kms.="" leve="" liga="" o=""> </jantes></p></Obs>
```

How can i strip the tags inside "obs" tag, keep the tag "obs" and also keep the text "I WANT THIS TEXT" ? Basically this:

```
<Obs>I WANT THIS TEXT</Obs>
```

For now this is the code i have:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(text);
        Queue<HtmlNode> nodes = new Queue<HtmlNode>(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("./*|./text()"));
        while (nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            HtmlNode node = nodes.Dequeue();
            HtmlNode parentNode = node.ParentNode;

            HtmlNodeCollection childNodes = node.SelectNodes("./*|./text()");

            if (childNodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode child in childNodes)
                {
                    if (child.Name != "obs")
                    {
                        nodes.Enqueue(child);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        childNodes = child.SelectNodes("//p|//jantes");
                        foreach (HtmlNode nodeToStrip in childNodes)
                            nodeToStrip.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToStrip);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string s = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Thanks :)

**EDIT 2**

Ok, i was able to complete the task. However this is taking too much time. About 3 hours and consuming 800MB in memory.

**Still needing help!**

Here is the code, it might help someone.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(text);
        Queue<HtmlNode> nodes = new Queue<HtmlNode>(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("./*|./text()"));
        while (nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            HtmlNode node = nodes.Dequeue();
            HtmlNode parentNode = node.ParentNode;

            HtmlNodeCollection childNodes = node.SelectNodes("./*|./text()");

            if (childNodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode child in childNodes)
                {
                    if (child.Name != "obs")
                    {
                        nodes.Enqueue(child);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        childNodes = child.SelectNodes("//p|//jantes");
                        if (childNodes != null)
                        {
                            foreach (HtmlNode nodeToStrip in childNodes)
                            {
                                var replacement = doc.CreateTextNode(nodeToStrip.InnerText);
                                nodeToStrip.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(replacement, nodeToStrip);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string s = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)? Among its claims:

> - the parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML
> - you can fix a page the way you want, modify the DOM, add nodes, copy nodes,    well... you name it

Comment: Didn't like Html Agility Pack for the purpose. It's very powerful though. But it took me 4 hours to "clean" the file :(